# Find all the index of matching elements in the multiple Array

Tags: c#, arrays

Suppose I have two arrays as follows

```
int[] first = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 14 };
int[] second = { 12, 13, 14, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 };
```

I want the result as follows:

```
matching index from the first = 6,7,8 
matching index from second = 0,1,2
```

**Condition: I cannot sort the array to find the index and there can be any number of the array.**

I am looking for some efficient solution and I will be glad for the help. 
Thanks in advance.

Below is the code I did for the two arrays:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] first = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 14 };
        int[] second = { 12, 13, 14, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 };
        IndexArray sameIndexArray = CompareArray(first, second);
        Console.WriteLine("FOLLOWING ARE THE INDEX WITH SAME VALUE FOR FIRST ARRAY");
        foreach (var index in sameIndexArray.FirstArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("FOLLOWING ARE THE INDEX WITH SAME VALUE FOR SECOND ARRAY");
        foreach (var index in sameIndexArray.SecondArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(index);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IndexArray CompareArray(int[] firstArray, int[] secondArray)
    {
        IndexArray arrayIndex = new IndexArray();
        arrayIndex.FirstArray = new List<int>();
        arrayIndex.SecondArray = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.Length; j++)
            {
                if (firstArray[i] == secondArray[j])
                {
                    arrayIndex.FirstArray.Add(i);
                    arrayIndex.SecondArray.Add(j);
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayIndex;
    }
}

public class IndexArray
{
    public List<int> FirstArray { get; set; }
    public List<int> SecondArray { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is O(N^2). An O(N) or O(N log N) solution should be possible:

- Create a HashSet for each of the sets
- iterate over the first set, filtering by hashset2.Contains and print the indexes
- do the same vice versa

Something like this:

```
private static IndexArray CompareArray(int[] firstArray, int[] secondArray)
{
    IndexArray arrayIndex = new IndexArray();
    var hashset2 = new HashSet<int>(secondArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (hashset2.Contains(firstArray[i]))
            arrayIndex.FirstArray.Add(i);
    }
    var hashset1 = new HashSet<int>(firstArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (hashset1.Contains(secondArray[i]))
            arrayIndex.SecondArray.Add(i);
    }

    return arrayIndex;
}
```

Comment: O(n) is not always faster than O(n*m).  This is multiple O(n)  operations

Comment: @paparazzo Sure, O(...) is a limit and for not too large N a factor might matter. But O(4*N) = O(N).

Comment: Still does not mean it is faster.   Cheers.   I know what O( ) means.

Comment: @paparazzo N = 10.000: original: 560 ms / mine: 1 ms; N = 100.000: original: 50000 ms / mine: 14 ms

Comment: No doubt you can contrive a case where your answer is faster.  If I contrive a case where the values are unique with a lot of overlap it would be faster.  Moving on.

Comment: I measured the time with random arrays: `Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(_ => random.Next(0, 1000)).ToArray()` which have by construction lots of overlap if N > 1000.

Comment: I have moved on.   Good day.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. But if I have the 40 different array  then I have to compare in 40 different loop to find out all the matching index between 40 different array. also the number of array is dynamic.

Comment: @klaus gutter I think the approach I did to achieve the solution is not the right way to do it. any other idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this is working code it might be a better fit on code review.

I would drop the

```
arrayIndex.FirstArray = new List<int>();
arrayIndex.SecondArray = new List<int>();
```

Add

```
public List<int> FirstArray  { get; } = new List<int>();
public List<int> SecondArray { get; } = new List<int>();
```

Arraylookup is fast but I would add

```
int first = firstArray[i];
```

And then use that.

WritelLine will write a line.

Comment: this example is just for the two array but I am asking for the efficient solution for any number of array. function should return me all the matching indexes on any number of array. Thanks.